# Javafx: How do you target objects in nested views?

Tags: javafx

I understand that for each time I load a nested fxml and controller that I can use that controller to manipulate the nested fxml. For example I can make every other row purple, but what I don't understand is how, after everything is loaded, can I target something specific to manipulate.

This is the most bare bones minimal replicate-able example I can make, anything reduced from this doesn't fit the criteria of a nested fxml and a child. What I want to do here is take the first score, with the text "Score0" and change it to "10" when the 10 button is pushed. I have a feeling I'm close, the score box should be score[0]. It should also be nested in row[0], but I can't seem to get the scoreEntry method to find the box to change it.

Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("view1.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 400, 300);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
}
```

view1.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.nested.Ctrl1">
<children>
  <VBox fx:id="rowHolder" prefHeight="260.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#scoreEntry" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" text="10" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="70.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="260.0" />
  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#scoreEntry" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" text="0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="260.0" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Ctrl1.java:

```
public class Ctrl1 {
@FXML
private VBox rowHolder;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    addRows();
}

public void addRows() {
    int rounds = 2;
    HBox row[];
    row = new HBox[rounds];
    String ctrlArray[];
    ctrlArray = new String[rounds];

    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        row[i] = new HBox();
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/nested/view2.fxml"));
            row[i] = loader.load();
            rowHolder.getChildren().add(row[i]);
            Ctrl2 ctrl2 = loader.getController();
            ctrlArray[i] = String.valueOf(ctrl2);

            ctrl2.setRoundNum(String.valueOf(i));
            System.out.println(row[i]);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ctrlArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Controller: " + ctrlArray[i]);
    }
}

private BigDecimal scoreInput;

private boolean numberInput;

@FXML
public void scoreEntry(ActionEvent event) {
    Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
    String buttonText = button.getText();

    if (buttonText.matches("[0-10\\.]")) {
        if (!numberInput) {
            numberInput = true;

            //TODO: find Label for input text

            //I think it should be something like "row[0].getChildren().score[0].clear();"
        }

        //And then I would append it with something like "score[0].appendText(buttonText);"
        return;
    }
}

}
```

view2.fxml

```
<HBox prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="400.0" style="-fx-background-color: #77e77e;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.nested.Ctrl2">
<children>
  <Label fx:id="rowNum" text="Row Number" />
  <HBox fx:id="scoresHolder" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
  <Label fx:id="subTotal" text="Sub Total" />
  <Label fx:id="total" text="Total" />
</children>
</HBox>
```

Ctrl2.java

```
public class Ctrl2 {

@FXML
private Label rowNum;

@FXML
private Label subTotal;

@FXML
private HBox scoresHolder;

@FXML
private Label total;

public void setRoundNum(String strRnd) {
    rowNum.setText(strRnd);
}

public void setSubTotal(String strRnd) {
    subTotal.setText(strRnd);
}

public void setTotal(String strRnd) {
    total.setText(strRnd);
}

@FXML
void initialize() {
    int plays = 1;
    Label score[];
    score = new Label[plays];
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        score[i] = new Label("Score" + i);
        scoresHolder.getChildren().add(score[i]);
        System.out.println(score[i]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Just put the controller instances in an array. As usual, it's completely unclear what the issue is.

Comment: Here is my guess based on the limited info.  I think you need a `POJO` to represent a row.  In my scores `HBox`, I would go ahead and add buttons that show each score as zero. On the click of one of those buttons, I would open a new window that would all someone to enter a score/change the text of that button.

Comment: @James_D the confusion lies in, isn't the rows array wrapping the controllers? Also I commented out how I think it should be written to get the box with the button. How should it be written?

Comment: @Sedrick that's not a bad idea, but it seems unelegant, especially when you have 20 rows of 6 score buttons. I'm hoping once I figure out how to call on Score0 I will be able to target any of them.

Comment: your buttons shared the same onaction event ¿ do you want to know wich button was pressed  when`scoreEntry()` is called?

Comment: Define a method in `Ctrl2` to do whatever it is you’re trying to do in `scoreEntry` to the row. Then keep an array of the controllers and call that method on the appropriate controller. Clearly `rows` does not hold an array of controllers - it’s an array of HBoxes.

Comment: @GiovanniContreras The buttons will look at what the text on the button is, match it to a number in the regex and then I can push that as a corresponding value. I think I've added an array to hold the controllers. I'm trying to figure out how to write a method to change text of score[i] in Ctrl2 now.

Comment: unrelated: don't hard-code sizing constraints of nodes

Comment: @kleopatra I assume you're referring to "int plays = 2;" that's just for the minimum reproduce-able example.

Comment: no, sizing constraints are pref/min/max height/width - which you set in your fxml on some nodes :) Doing so will prevent the layouts to do their jobs

Comment: @kleopatra oh, that was just to make the example quickly.

Comment: Another quetion - Why are you not using `ListView`?

Comment: @Sedrick If I want to insert different types of rows, like a subtotal row, the ListView fell apart for me. It also didn't seem to help me access nested objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took @James_D's advice and wrapped my controllers and cells in arrays.

```
 //This is the array for the controllers. It's outside the method to be accessed by other methods.
public static Ctrl2[] ctrlArray = new Ctrl2[2];

public void addRows() {
    int rounds = 2;
    HBox row = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/nested/view2.fxml"));
            row = loader.load();
            rowHolder.getChildren().add(row);
            ctrlArray[i] = loader.getController();

            ctrlArray[i].setRoundNum(String.valueOf(i));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ctrlArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Controller: " + ctrlArray[i]);
    }
}
```

The problem I was having was with scope. If I make the array holder outside the method I can access it from other methods.

```
private Label[] score;

public void addScores() {
    int plays = 2;
    //Moved array holder from here to outside
    score = new Label[plays];
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        score[i] = new Label("Score" + i);
        scoresHolder.getChildren().add(score[i]);
        System.out.println(score[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: now addScores()  can acces to ctrlArray